# Guidance on becoming a pilot

Tags: flight-school, cpl

Can anyone tell me which pilot training institute is best for getting CPL in India?

What other things are needed to be done along with CPL in order to become a co-pilot in an airliner?

Comment: Welcome to Aviation.SE! Specific recommendations like this are off topic here (a quick trip through the [Tour](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/tour) should help you out. However, we have some other questions on [what to look for in a flight school](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/14411/how-to-choose-a-flight-school) and [what to look for in a flight instructor](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9869/what-to-look-for-in-a-flight-instructor) that should help you out.

Comment: @FreeMan the link you shared is for Italy.

Comment: That is very true, but if you look at [Dave's answer](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/14414/5517) you'll see nothing in there that's specific to Italy. Actually his answer is US-centric, based on his experience, but I don't think any of his points about _what to look for_ are specific to any country.